# How to count the key characters?

Tags: java, string

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class chara{

   public static void main(String[]args){


     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

     System.out.println("Input a string");

     String user=input.nextLine();

     if(user.length()<7)

     {

        return;

     }

     else

    {



    }

    System.out.println("now input a letter to be replaced");

    String letter = input.next();

    String user2 = user.replace(letter, "-");

    String user3 = user.replace(letter, "");

    System.out.println(user2);

    System.out.println(user3);

  }
}
```

the code needs to do three things take a string and a letter and :

1. replace the key letter in the string with "-"
2. remove the key letter of the string
3. count the amount of times the key letter appears.

At present I have two problems. I don't know how to count the amount of times the letter 
appears because technically it is a string and not a char and i do not know how to count 
strings. Second, I need to make it so that if the strings are not of the desired length it 
simply asks again instead of exiting the program. I have tried to use the getString() method but for some reason it always says that the method is undefined.

Comment: a String is an array of chars.

Comment: Maybe do some research on how to loop back and ask the question again and again depending on whether the input is what you need. That would be the java keywords "for" or "do" or "while" that are involved in looping.

Comment: Counting will be a similar problem. One way is to search starting at column 0 for the character, count it if found and loop to search starting just past the column you found it in. Another strategy is to convert the String to an array of char (char[]) and then loop through the array checking and counting. Those are some things you could Google for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With full credit to user1324109 for their solution to issue #1, here is how you can solve your issue #2:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user1 = "", user2 = "", user3 = "";
        int count = 0;
        while(user1.equals("") || user1.length() < 7) {
            System.out.println("Input a string");
            user1 = input.nextLine();
        }
        if(!user1.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("now input a letter to be replaced");
            String letter = input.next();
            user2 = user1.replace(letter, "-");
            user3 = user1.replace(letter, "");
            System.out.println(user2);
            System.out.println(user3);
            count += (user1.length() - user3.length());
            System.out.println("letter was found to be present "+count+" times");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For issue #1:

Near the top of the main method:

```
int count = 0;
```

After user3 is assigned:

```
count += (user3.length() - user.length());
```

Comment: that was very helpful, thank you. Ironically enough i had just found a way to convert strings to char but this is easier so thank you

Comment: lol also i switched to user-user3 because i was getting a negative number

Answer (score 0):

To help with issue #3:

```
    int count = 0;

    for(char c : user.toCharArray() ){
        if ( c ==  letter.charAt(0)) count++;
    }

    System.out.println("Number of occurences: "+count);
```